# weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.CallableProcessingInterceptor

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, jar, weblogic

Getting this error when i try to deploy a project (**no Maven**) with Weblogic Server. If i deploy with Weblogic **12.1.3** the error is

> ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver.class

, and with WebLogic **12.2.1.4** the error is the following (error in the same jar):

[image]

It could be a jar conflict, but i have only one jar for org.springframework.web. In Properties -> Build Path i have all the jars inside WebApp Libraries:

[image]

The hierarchy, on Eclipse, is:

```
├── Ear project
├── Web project
    └── Java Resources
        └── resources
        └── src (packages with Java classes)
        └── Libraries (with all the jars imported from WEB-INF)
    └── lib (some javax jar)
    └── Web Content
        └── assets
        └── META-INF
        └── WEB-INF
```

The project works on another machine. So what is the problem in my environment?

My *weblogic.application.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.2/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <!--weblogic-version:10.3.5.0-->
    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.joda.time.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.soap.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>org.springframework.*</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, removing all the jar files from *Webapp Libraries* in Eclipse (Right click on the web project and *Build Path/Libraries*) and adding them on *Build Path* of the EAR project.